# How to set Javascript properties in Android webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am building an Android application that loads a web application in to a web view. When a user visits the web application in a browser a pop up asking if they want to bookmark the page appears.

For the native app I want remove this.

For iPhone I was able to do this:

```
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"AppConfig.showBookmarkPrompt=false;"];
```

For Android I tried this:

```
@Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){"+
                "AppConfig.showBookmarkPrompt=false;})()");
    }
```

The Android version doesn't work. I presume that the javascript is being run after the bookmark popup has been shown. I don't really know why the iPhone version does works and not the Android.

There are many other ways I can achieve my goals but I am wondering if anybody can explain why the iPhone method works and if there is something similar in Android. I have been reading about it through Google searches but it is still not entirely clear to me.

Thanks for any help I get.

EDIT

The problem was for Android I was passing a function in JavaScript where I should have just set the property like this: view.loadUrl("javascript:AppConfig.showBookmarkPrompt=false;");

There must be some difference in the way it is executed that I don't quite understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put this on onCreate() of Activity..

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

then call your code...

```
 @Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl("javascript:AppConfig.showBookmarkPrompt=false");
}
```

For more info look at [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html).

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Unfortunately I had already setJavaScriptEnabled(true) in onCreate, I had then set the WebViewClient with the onPageFinished function and finally I load the URL. The bookmark popup is still shown. The show bookmark popup function is run 1 second after page load. It appears in this (Android) case the property is not changed before that but it is in the iPhone app. Very confusing.

Comment: have you looked at the link I suggested as above.?

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion was correct. The problem was the Javascript I was passing in. I have edited my question to show what I was doing wrong. Thank you very much for you help.